# How to stub a function inside lambda

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, aws-lambda, sinon

I am developing a Lambda function that internally contains multiple function 
I need to check how many times the internal functions are called

this is my handler file source.js

```
exports.handler = () =>{
  function function_1 ()
  {
    returns something;
  }
  function function_2 ()
  {
    //calls functions_1 internally and 
    returns something;
  }

  function_2();
}
```

this is what i've tried.
test.spect.js

```
const handler = require('./source').handler,
      sinon = require('sinon'),
      stub = require('sinon').stub
      
describe('testing lambdas',()=>{
  let myspy = spy(handler,'function_2');
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(myspy)

})
```

It gives me this error `Attempted to wrap undefined property anotherMethod as function`

Comment: You can't, these two functions are private. You can't get it via `handler.function_2`

Comment: Then how do i do it ?